# how to parameterized queries in asp.net?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, parameterized-query

I've learned that string concatenation is prone to SQL injection, which sadly I have already applied to most of my code. I'm trying to incorporate parameterized queries but somehow the examples online doesn't answer my problem. Most examples that i saw is this:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductID = @Id";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Request.QueryString["Id"]);
```

But what if i have an sql statement like this:

```
public static void CreateLingerieBrandsDatabase(string brand)
{
    SqlConnection createBrandData = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Y560\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LingerieItemsDB;Integrated Security=True");
    createBrandData.Open();
    SqlCommand cmdBrandData = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE lingerieItem" + brand + "(id int,type char(50),model char(50),price float,image1 char(255),image2 char(255),description text, [neck type], [color] char(50)); ", createBrandData);
    cmdBrandData.ExecuteNonQuery();
    createBrandData.Close();
}
```

Also, I'm getting the value of string brand in a textbox, which will be passed on to CreateLingerieBrandsDatabase method. then it will pass on to the string concatenation. By the way, the reason why im using string concatenation to the table name is because i have created 3 separate tables for each brand like lingerieItemGlamory, lingerieItemEvgenia and lingerieItemVictoria. The moment that the administrator enters Glamory in the textbox and then click submit, It will know which database table to access.

EDITED: As for the above example, it will create new database that has the same table name as the 3 previous brands(except for the concatenated part) that I have mentioned. So when it is time to access it, it will know what brands to access.

I know my code is messy and I'm still a beginner. I hope you guys can suggest better solutions for me and improve my code. Giving actual examples is also highly appreciated. mwah!

Comment: You can't parameterize identifiers. That means that you can't use parameters on ddl statements. However, creating tables is a design time operation, not a run time operation. It's almost never a good idea to let users handle the database structure. Also, you should not keep multiple tables with the same structure for different brands - instead, create a single table and add a column to indicate the brand.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - I see. Okay, i'll definitely brainstorm about that changes.

Comment: Usually, you'd fix this by realising that your data model is broken. You're embedding *data* (brand names) in *metadata* (table names) rather than modelling it as data. If you had a *single* `lingerieItems` table that included a `brand` column then this (and very many other) queries will suddenly become *easier* to write and open to basic parameterization.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Okay well noted sir damian.

Comment: I have also one more question, what if the administrator is the only one who has access on creating database tables in the website. Will it still be prone to SQL injection?

Answer (score 0):

A table name cannot be substituted by a parameter. You have to compose the name by concatenation. And since the brand names seem to be limited to a certain predefined list, just check the `brand` variable value against that list to avoid SQL injection, e.g.:

```
public static void CreateLingerieBrandsDatabase(string brand)
{
    SqlConnection createBrandData = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Y560\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LingerieItemsDB;Integrated Security=True");
    createBrandData.Open();
    if (!Regex.Match(brand, @"^(?:Glamory|Evgenia|Victoria)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success)
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid brand");
    SqlCommand cmdBrandData = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE lingerieItem" + brand + "(id int,type char(50),model char(50),price float,image1 char(255),image2 char(255),description text, [neck type], [color] char(50)); ", createBrandData);
    cmdBrandData.ExecuteNonQuery();
    createBrandData.Close();
}
```

Comment: Oh i see. By checking it, it prevents unwanted input. Impressive!

Comment: I reviewed again your solution and I've noticed that it prevents me from creating new brands aside from Glamory,Evgenia and Victoria. So close for an interesting solution but I might need to tweak this.

Comment: Yes, the `^(?:Glamory|Evgenia|Victoria)$` was just an example. You should be extended if the actual list is longer. If the list is really long, you may compose the regex string this way: `var brandsRegexStr = "^(?:" + string.Join("|", brands) + ")$";` and later use it as `if (!Regex.Match(brand, brandsRegexStr, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)...`. Here I'm assuming `brands` is an array or a list of strings with brand names.